# How can I download a Google Drive folder that is shared with me (without Google silently missing out subfolders / files)

Tags: google-drive

Google never ceases to annoy with their unfixed bugs. How can we workaround this one?

Suppose someone has shared a google drive folder with you. And you need to download this folder. But it contains lots of subfolders and documents (6-7 levels deep).

When you try to download this from the browser then Google Drive normally initiates the zipping process. It doesn't throw any errors and starts the download. But the problem is that it silently skips all files inside the last child folder - without throwing any errors.

You might think that all the files have been downloaded until you start seeing the problems.

The current workaround that I know of is to check the last child folder contents individually and redownload whatever has been left out. But it's ridiculous having to do this in 2021 from Google's app.

If you try to use scripts that would download from drive recursively then Google blocks those attempts.

How can you download from Drive without missing files in your folders?